# Dynamically adding a user control to a repeater

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, repeater

I have a class (MyClass) which represents a nested hierarchy, so the class has a property which is a collection of MyClass.  MyClass also has a title property

To show it on a web page, I was hoping to create a user control which had a repeater. In the item template I would have literal to display the title property, and on the ItemCreated event of the repeater, I would create a new instance of the usercontrol, and add it into the current item in the repeater.

My problem is, when the Page_Load event in the usercontrol fires, if the control was dynamically added, the repMyClass repeater poroperty is null, even if I call EnsureChildControls.  Am I missing something here?  If I create a repeater and drop my userctonrol in the item template it works fine. My can't I get this to work dynamically?

User Control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyControl" %>
Items:<br/>
<asp:Repeater ID="repMyClass" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
    OnItemCreated="repMenuItems_ItemCreated">
    <HeaderTemplate><ul><HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%# Eval("Title") %>
            <div><asp:PlaceHolder ID="SubItemPlaceholder" runat="server" /></div>
        </li></ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

User Control Code:

```
public partial class MyControl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public IEnumerable<MyClass> ChildItems { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.repMyClass.DataSource = ChildItems;
        this.repMyClass.DataBind();
    }

    protected void repMenuItems_ItemCreated(object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs  e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            //Get the MyClass instance for this repeater item
            MyClass mcCurrent = (MyClass)e.Item.DataItem;

            //If the MyClass instance has child instances
            if (mcCurrent.Children != null && mcCurrent.Children.Length > 0)
            {
                //Add a new user control and set it's property so it can bind
                PlaceHolder ph = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("SubItemPlaceholder");

                MyControl ctl = (MyControl)Page.LoadControl(typeof(MyControl),new object[] {});

                ctl.ChildItems = mcCurrent.Children;
                ph.Controls.Add(ctl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit this to explain and maybe clean this up.  I think maybe you had half an edit in this sentence that didn't get completed?  "My problem is, when the Page_Load event first for controls that were dynamically added, the repNyClass repeater poroperty is null"

Answer (score 3):

I had done this a long time ago for creating nested reports using Accordions.

In Index, when you want to dynamically add User Control instances:

```
// Declare Placeholder    
PlaceHolder ph = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("SubItemPlaceholder")

// Adding some literal controls to header
ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("This is the accordion header!!"));

// Declare new control variable
crt = new Control();

// Load up your User Control
crt = LoadControl("~/MyControl.ascx");

// Check if it has loaded properly
if (crt != null)
{
    // GET / SET any custom properties of the User Control
    ((myClass)crt).title = "Welcome";

    // Add the new User Control to the placeholder's controls collection
    ph.Controls.Add(crt);
}
```

**Note:**  
In the User Control, you must add the **"ClassName"** in the declaration tag

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="myTest" ClassName="myClass" %>
```

Also, any properties you wish to expose when creating instances dynamically, you declare them as follows:

```
public string title { get; set; }
```

So if you want to force a value when creating for "repMyClass" you can set it as a property and assign whatever value you want to it programmaticaly.

Comment: The problem is, my user control has it's own child controls (a repeater in this case).  In the page_load event of the user control, the repeater variable is actually null.  I can't set it myself, the asp.net framework needs to.

Comment: @Jeremy : Sure you can. Just create a property of type repeater. You can then access it, instantize it, do whatever you want with it. Please clarify - according to me you should have a public property in the UserControl, in the Page Load of the UserControl you should be using that public property to bind data to the repeater. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can make another constructor in the control that takes the property you want and use it in the load event, and then pass it in the currently empty object array in LoadControl() call.

Another approach is to fire the logic in the setter of the property instead of in the Load event of the control, since is essentially the real load here and fires once per request per control if I get it right.

Another approach is not to load it dynamically as all.

inside your item template you can have something like:

```
<uc:MyControl runat="server 
    ChildItems='<%# ((MyClass) Container.DataItem).Children %>'
    Visible='<%# ((MyClass) Container.DataItem).Children.Length > 0 %>'
    />
```

**Update**

One more approach that never gave me errors with child controls in user controls inside repeaters or page life cycle, is to use the Item Data Bound event instead of the Item Created.

Actually, when I think about it now, your code shouldn't because e.Item.DataItem hasn;t been bound to yet.

Try to change the event to ItemDataBound and see if this works.

.

I still though recommend you include the control in the item markup, and control the visibility of the control in the event (now to be ItemDataBound). You can refer to the control by something like `e.Item.FindControl("ControlId") as MyControl` (will return null if not found in current item).

Try combining both, or at least changing event to data bound instead of created, and let's see...

Comment: The problem is, my user control has it's own child controls (a repeater in this case).  In the page_load event of the user control, the repeater variable is actually null.  I can't set it myself, the asp.net framework needs to.

Comment: The theory is that you shouldn't need to use the load, use the setter instead. Another alternative is in the answer update, that one might fix the issue. I think the problem is the event used, this has very good probability of being the issue.